# MySql INSERT...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE with partial VALUES

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I have a list of possibly-incomplete set of values that will be used to append to or update a MySql table using the INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE construct. The requirements are as follows:

- If an operation resolves to an INSERT and the field value IS supplied, use the value supplied;
- If an operation resolves to an INSERT and the field value IS NOT supplied, use the field's table DEFAULT value;
- If an operation resolves to an UPDATE and the field value IS supplied, use the value supplied;
- If an operation resolves to an UPDATE and the field value IS NOT supplied, retain the current (table) field value.

I've come up with the following statement, but the clauses wrapped in ** are erroneous and I'm having difficulty expressing them:

```
INSERT INTO `test` 
(`id`, `num`, `text`)
VALUES 
('1', 100, 'aaa'), 
('2', 200, DEFAULT),
('3', DEFAULT, 'ccc')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`num`  = IF (**VALUES(`num`)  = DEFAULT**, `num`,  VALUES(`num`)), 
`text` = IF (**VALUES(`text`) = DEFAULT**, `text`, VALUES(`text`));
```

Notes: `id` is the unique key. Both `num` and `text` have default (NOT NULL) values set.

Things I've tried, but aren't satisfactory:

1. Replacing DEFAULT in VALUES with NULL, and then test for, e.g.,  `IF (VALUES (num) = NULL ...`. This works, but will insert NULL on INSERT (and generate a warning - e.g., "Column 'text' cannot be null"), which is not acceptable - I need to have the default value applied to the missing fields;
2. Using something like 'xxx' instead of DEFAULT for missing values, and testing for 'xxx' (STRCMP), but this will insert 'xxx' in case of INSERT;
3. I've not tried this as I can't find the command/proper syntax, but the idea is to test (in the IF clause) whether `num` and `text` in VALUES are literals (num or string) or a MySql keyword (i.e., DEFAULT) - possibly using regex? -  and then act accordingly.

Of course, an alternative to the above might entail obtaining existing values from the database and/or hardcoding into the query the default values for the missing fields, but I trust the same result can be achieved more elegantly using a single MySql statement.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: You don't need the `IF`. `VALUES(num)` will be whatever is in the `VALUES` list, so if it says `DEFAULT` you'll get the default value.

Comment: You can't test for `NULL` with `=`, you have to write `IF(VALUES(num) IS NULL, ...)`

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. However I only want to DEFAULT applied upon INSERT;  if the operation for that particular row is an UPDATE, I'd like to retain the current table value wherever it says DEFAULT in VALUES(). (Noted, re. `IS NULL`).

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. There's no way to tell if a value is explicitly supplied with a value that happens to be the same as the default, or has the keyword `DEFAULT`. Where are the values coming from, maybe something can be done at that end.

Comment: Yes, there are pre-processing solutions I can think of, like first getting the current state of the table, comparing to the input data and then stringing the query accordingly, but was hoping for a query-based approach that does no require a read and unnecessary processing prior to the insert. Data is coming from a quick-entry form with only the ability of enforcing datatypes for values supplied.

Comment: The problem is that the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause doesn't have access to the syntax that was used, just the values. Could you just pre-populate the form with the original values? So if they want to keep the same value they just leave it un-edited.

Comment: Yep, think I'll have to resort to that. Cheers man.